# How to read excel file row by row and pass it in a curl command?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

So I'm trying to read an excel file and pass it into a curl command. So in my curl command, I need 4 things. I need the name, path,Tname, and format.

So for me to run this script all I need to do is parse the excel file. It should get the data by parsing it by column. So in the column, I have the headers such as name, path, and format. I'm trying to make it so that it reads the column and takes the data from there and sends it into the curl command. Once it passes then it should go to the next row and do the same until it gets to the end.

So my curl command I know the problem that needs to be fixed. I'm not concerned about the curl command at the moment. I'm more concern on how to get the data and sending it into the curl command.

I've gotten the excel sheet by using pandas. once I did that I appended each column into an array. Then in my curl command, I'm trying to pass it.

I'm using * in my url and user and pass for privacy reasons. Like I said i'm not concern about the curl command. I'm trying to fix my code on getting the data and sending it into the curl command.

```
import requests
import json
import pprint
import urllib
import sys
import pandas as pd

path='data.xlsx'
excel=pd.read_excel(path)
name = []
path = []
Tname = []
formatG = []
for cell in excel:
    name.append(cell[:0]),
    path.append(cell[:1]),
    Tname.append(cell[:2]),
    formatG.append(cell[:3])

url='*'
data={
           'name':'{}'.format(name),
           'path':'{}'.format(path),
           'TName':'{}'.format(Tname),
           'formatG':'{}'.format(formatG)           
     }

djson=json.dumps(data)
headers={'content-type':'application/json','Authorization':'token' {}.format(fk)}
response=requests.post(url,data=data_json,headers=headers)
pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a csv file has comma separated data like below for example:

```
name,path,Tname,formatG
tom,vv,teto,mp4
mane,bb,memo,png
```

then you can use a code like below:

```
data = []
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.strip().split(','))

data = data[1:]  # get the data without the first row which is data headers
print(data)

for entry in data:  
    name, path, Tname, formatG = entry
    # do your curl stuff
```

data looks like:

```
[['tom', 'vv', 'teto', 'mp4'], ['mane', 'bb', 'memo', 'png']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
data_list = []
for cell in excel: data_list.append({'name':cell[:0],'path':cell[:1]),'TName':cell[:2]),'formatG':cell[:3]})
url='*'
headers={'content-type':'application/json','Authorization':'token' {}.format(fk)}
for i in data_list: response=requests.post(url,data=i,headers=headers)
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks so if I do this. Would it read the data by column by column

Comment: I mean include this in your code. Don't just replace it. Better find a way to convert the read data into a bigger list with name `excel` from where you can read small lists.